# Are there examples of abuses of diplomatic immunity?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, diplomatic-immunity

Has there ever been a blatant abuse of diplomatic immunity for a serious crime? I am thinking along the lines of has anyone ever committed a murder, rape, manslaughter, and not been punished by their home country?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Yvonne_Fletcher

Comment: Where to even begin? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_immunity#Uses_and_abuses

Comment: Also this is too broad imo. How are you going to decide which answer is best. What if the punishment is a cover up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Jamal_Khashoggi etc. Of if only US persnonnel is involved https://www.stripes.com/news/marine-involved-in-crash-that-killed-romanian-rock-star-is-back-in-u-s-1.27110 Perhaps more recent examples exist from Iraq, Pakistan or Afghanistan. All of which are going to be controversial.

Comment: This one is probably not solved yet: https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/26/world/asia/us-military-attache-crash-pakistan.html Or maybe it is https://www.hindustantimes.com/world-news/us-official-involved-in-fatal-crash-paid-blood-money-to-leave-pakistan-reports/story-Htn21OuIElNxDCJuqopSvJ.html

Answer (score 3):

A Russian agent who has allegedly **murdered** another Russian (using a radioactive Weapon of Mass Destruction), was granted immunity on Russia to avoid any prosecution by the British officials.

> After the 2006 death of Alexander V. Litvinenko, the last known former Russian intelligence operative to be poisoned on British soil, British officials tried in vain to get their hands on the two prime suspects, Andrei K. Lugovoi, a former K.G.B. bodyguard, and Dmitri V. Kovtun, a Red Army deserter. Despite volumes of evidence, including a trail of radioactive polonium that investigators were able to trace practically to Moscow, Russia refused to hand over the two men. Mr. Lugovoi later [became a member of Parliament](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/24/world/europe/russia-uk-poison-charlie-rowley.html), **giving him immunity** from prosecution at home.

---

The Russian Embassy in Argentina has allegedly played a key role in **drug trafficking**:

> [**400kg of cocaine seized at Russian embassy in Argentina**](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/02/23/400kg-cocaine-seized-russian-embassy-argentina/)
>
> Police in Argentina have foiled a plot to smuggle cocaine to Europe through the Russian embassy’s **diplomatic courier** service, following an elaborate sting operation involving a shadowy Moscow intelligence chief.

---

The Russian Embassy in London is allegedly involved in the delivery of a Weapon of Mass Destruction on the territory of the UK:

> [**'Unusual activity' at Russian embassy before novichok attack**](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/mar/04/unusual-activity-russian-embassy-novichok-attack-skripal-poisonings)
>
> Intelligence services investigated unusual activity at the **Russian embassy** in London in the days before and after the novichok poisoning, it has been reported.

---

All crimes above — murder, drug trafficking, and WMD — are considered serious crimes in many countries, and the punishment includes death penalty.

Comment: @J.D (1) "Novichok" is a Chemical Weapon. (2) Chemical weapons **[are classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_weapon) as weapons of mass destruction** (WMDs)

Comment: It's worth noting that the Russian government waived immunity and worked with the Argentinians on the drug trafficking bust.

Comment: Did Lugovoi have [**diplomatic** immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_immunity) in the UK? You seem to be confusing it with [parliamentary immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_immunity) (in his home country).

Comment: @Fizz, you're right. *"…and not been punished by their home country"* made me think that the question did not restrict to a specific kind of immunity, but instead asked for examples of how immunity helped criminals evade prosecution, especially if that happens *with the aid* of their home country. I will amend my answer once the OP makes this point clear.

Comment: The first example seems to be a case of refusing extradition, rather than diplomatic immunity. Based just on what you posted here, I would assume that if he were to travel to the UK, the UK would be free to prosecute him. I think the question is asking "Has anyone evaded prosecution in the host country AND in their home country", not  "Has anyone evaded prosecution in the host country OR in their home country"

Comment: Answer full of assumptions) I think this is one of the most assu,ptional-based answer I've seen here.